# Target ajaxSubmit to a popup window

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, popup

I have a form that needs to be validated before submit, POST to a popup window, then the form needs to be reset afterwards.

I know the `target="newWindowName"` and `onsubmit="window.open('','newWindowName','')"` form attributes work, but this doesn't let me do anything after submit.

I know I can use `$('form').ajaxSubmit()` to specify an after-submit function, but it doesn't seem to let me open a new window.

How can I do all these things at once?

This is my form:

```
<form id="myForm" target="newWindow" autocomplete="on" action="/myUrl" method="post">
```

This is my javascript:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#myForm').valid()) {
        var options = {
            target: '',
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                this.target = "newWindow"; 
                window.open("", "newWindow", "width=500,height=450");
            },
            success: function () {
                hideForm();
                $('#myForm').resetForm();
            }
        };

        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up going with that was much more elegant.

```
<form id="myForm" target="newWindow" autocomplete="on" action="/myUrl" method="post">
```

And then the JS:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        var f = this;
        window.open("",$(this).attr("target"),"width=500,height=500"); 
        setTimeout(function () {  // delay resetting the form until after submit
            hideForm();
            f.reset();
        }, 0);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();  // only prevent default if the form is not valid
    } 
    return false;
});
```

This way, the new window will only show up if the form is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea using a `target` attribute in your form tag.  That will automatically submit the form to the window named "newWindow".  (To always submit to a *new* window, use `target="_blank"`.)

The trouble is you are preventing the form from being submitted to that new window, and then using JavaScript to do an ajax submit.  If you remove that extra code you'll get what you want:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        var f = this;
        setTimeout(function () {  // delay resetting the form until after submit
            hideForm();
            f.reset();
        }, 0);
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();  // only prevent default if the form is not valid
    } 
});
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2x6wL/